# Is a question that turns out to be a bug-report a valid question for SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

If someone reports a problem, and others cannot find a mistake in the code, it may turn out to be a bug in the software used.

Basically, I was wondering if SO is a valid platform for apparent bug-reports and/or bug-investigations?

If not, how do we deal with these questions?

Example:
[Pyramid returning wrong Content-Type HTTP header for static assets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13737888/708221)

Comment: For example? This is a bit too vague...

Comment: Do you expect the maintainers of the software to check Stack Overflow for bug reports? If no, then I wouldn't post it there. And even if so: What about a bug report is an actual question?

Comment: @ʞɔɥls I don't know if maintainers do or do not follow their own tags on SO. I don't have a particular bug myself, it's just that I have come across such questions a few times. Oftentimes these questions start out as users asking for help with an error. Only if several people do not see a user-mistake it may turn out to be a bug.

Comment: PS with regard to the example: This question may definitely be of value to me and other mod_wsgi users, I am not trying to get rid of it, just trying to get a feel for this.

Comment: I see now. I understood "bug report" as an actual reporting of the bug *in the question*. If you ask a valid question and it turns out to be a bug, so be it, but that should of course be in the answer (or the question could be closed as *too localized* if that bug makes the problem unsolvable).

Comment: Furthermore, if you can figure out a workaround, you can post it as an answer. Here's an example that recently happened to me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13804194/1015495

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Such a question can definitely be valid for SO.

*Especially* if it's not clear from the beginning if the problem is a bug or not.

And this would be an appropriate answer:

> It's a bug in line 42 of `foo.lang`, where they use `>` instead of `>=`. I've filed a bug report at http://thebugtracker.example.com/issue/42 and a workaround is to frobnicate the baz before calling `foo`.

Comment: No, you should frobnicate the bar before calling foo.